# RegEx to use only one * instead of two

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I was working on this regex that I use in preg_replace to add `divs` and `/divs` around text that has `*` around it. It right now use two `*`s. What would be a sure way to do it with only one `*`

**Current**

```
<?php

$errors = 1;

$arr['ERR'] = '';
$arr['ERR'] .= '*<i>Error 1</i>*';
$arr['ERR'] .= '*<i>Error 2</i>*';
$arr['ERR'] .= '*<i>Error 3</i>*';
$arr['ERR'] .= '*<i>Error 4</i>*';
$arr['ERR'] .= '*<i>Error 5</i>*';
$arr['TOF'] = 'Success';

$arr = preg_replace('#\*(.+?)\*#', '<div>$1</div>', $arr);

print_r( $arr );
// output


array (
    [ERR] => <div><i>Error 1</i></div><div><i>Error 2</i></div><div><i>Error 3</i></div><div><i>Error 4</i></div><div><i>Error 5</i></div>
    [TOF] => Success
)



?>
```

**Attempting**

```
$arr['ERR'] = '';
$arr['ERR'] .= '*<i>Error 1</i>';
$arr['ERR'] .= '*<i>Error 2</i>';
$arr['ERR'] .= '*<i>Error 3</i>';
$arr['ERR'] .= '*<i>Error 4</i>';
$arr['ERR'] .= '*<i>Error 5</i>';
$arr['TOF'] = 'Success';

$arr = preg_replace('#\*(.+?)#', '<div>$1</div>', $arr);

//just one * but get the same results as above.
```

How can the regex be done to use only one `*`

Comment: What about `*<i>Error 1</*i>`? Shouldn't you write a parser that has some checks/validation if you're trying to do something like this? Ie. simple RegEx like this *assumes **no** mistakes*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
\*(.+?)(?![^*])
```

The lookahead asserts that the match is before another star or at the end of the match.

Here is a [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/xS0wC1/2).

Comment: Works, but does not replace all. And no, there wont be any <*/> because those message are hard coded. I'm beginning them with a * to indicate they are error messages.

Comment: Not another star. There may not be another star after. So `*<i>Error 1</i> = <div><i>Error 1</i></div>` or `*<i>Error 1</i>*<i>Error 2</i> = <div><i>Error 1</i></div><div><i>Error 2</i></div>`

Comment: Ok. Thanks for helping. Do I do like this `$arr = preg_replace('#\*(.+?)(?![^*])#', '<div>$1</div>', $arr);` or do I need the `/g` in there like in your demo?

Comment: Use the one you posted, it's correct. `/g` modifier is for the engine, and PHP engine is `g`eneral by default.